# Updating compilers without updating the system

Tags: 10.04, 9.10

I am running Karmic but would like to update GCC etc. to Lucid. Can this be done and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use new GCC along your existing, not upgrading it. You can find a required deb package or download binaries googling it.

Upgrading your default compiler can do a lot of harm to Your system.